# php format parsing and changing. Date format is always two characters

Tags: php

This is my date format:

```
d.m.y
```

but I need it like `dd.mm.yy`

How can with php check format and if is `d.m.y` then convert it to `dd.mm.yy` and if is already `dd.mm.yy` leave it.

If is `y-m-d` conver it to `yy-mm-dd`

How can i do with regex?

Why regex. Because my datum is CONSTANT. And for each installation is different. But for some cases must be not d.m.y but dd.mm.yy for example.

but can be some other format also.

Comment: You need to give examples of your date format. `d.m.y` _can't display most dates_

Comment: What does `dd.mm.yy` mean? It doesn't seem you're referring to the letters used in `date()`, so could you give some concrete examples?

Comment: Sample input/output would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
$date = date('d.m.y', strtotime($your_date))
```

or

```
$date = new DateTime($your_date);
echo $date->format('d.m.y');
```

Comment: it is not necessary d.m.y. It is just example

Comment: @senzacionale: Well than, use whatever format you need, or don't use any: refer to my answer for details

Answer (score 2):

```
$show_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.Y', $dateInput)->format('Y-m-d');
```

[DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

Comment: it is not necessary d.m.y. It is just example

Comment: @senzacionale try it out and let me know if it working or not

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01'); /// you need to convert you input date to this format
echo $date->format('d-m-y');
```

Comment: it is not necessary d.m.y. It is just example

Comment: You need to convert your date format to `'YYYY-MM-DD'` format as shown in answer then using `format` function you can convert it to any format